# Can thread sleep when it got interrupted?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

In `waitComplete` I have a synchronized block with waiting on the lock. My concern is that scheduled interrupt will fire before it gets to wait. Will main thread be allowed to wait when interrupted flag is on?

```
try {
    executor.schedule(currentThread::interrupt,100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    completor.waitComplete();
    fail();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--):

> Throws:
>       InterruptedException - if any thread interrupted the current thread **before or** while the current thread was waiting for a notification.

(emphasis mine)